# CRC-8 value mismatch

Tags: crc

I'm trying to understand how a protocol works, it's from a [TEC-Microsystem device (DX5100)](https://www.tec-microsystems.com//Download/Manuals/DX5100/DX5100%20Commands%20v3.12%20eng.pdf), it says:

> CRC: Byte of the control sum CRC-8. It can be absent in some options
>   of the protocol. The control sum CRC-8 is calculated before the
>   stuffing for the entire packet, beginning with the byte FEND and
>   finishing with the last databyte. If a packet transmits an address,
>   when calculating the control sum, its true value is used, i.e. MSB=1
>   is not taken into account. For the calculation of the control sum the
>   polynomial is used. CRC = X8 + X5 + X4 + 1.

When I sniff the data being sent by their software, I see this data being transmitted:

```
0xC0 0x81 0x04 0x02 0x02 0x00 0x55
```

> If a packet transmits an address,
>   when calculating the control sum, its true value is used, i.e. MSB=1
>   is not taken into account

This means that the data taken into account to compute the CRC is actually `0xC0 0x01 0x04 0x02 0x02 0x00` (second byte is `0x01` instead of `0x81`).

According to what I could find on wikipedia, "CRC = X8 + X5 + X4 + 1" means they use "CRC-8-Dallas/Maxim".

However, when I use https://crccalc.com/, enter `C00104020200` and hit "CALC-CRC-8" it reports `0x82` for "CRC-8/MAXIM", not `0x55`. Am I missing something?

More examples from the sniffer:

- `C0 81 03 02 02 00 D3`, so `C0 01 03 02 02 00` CRC is `D3`
- `C0 81 05 02 02 00 DA`, so `C0 01 05 02 02 00` CRC is `DA`

Comment: Note the initial CRC is set to 0xDE, but I couldn't get that to match either. Could you add one or two more examples to your question?

Comment: @rcgldr: "initial CRC is set to 0xDE", where does this come from?

Comment: @rcgldr: Got t in the doc "Before the calculation the number DEh initializes the value"...so likely https://crccalc.com/ cannot help as this cannot be specified. I'll try to sniff another command.

Comment: Try this calculator instead: [online crc calculator](http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html). Select CRC8 MAXIM, then click on the dot next to "custom" to change the parameters.

Comment: @rcgldr: This link is great, but as you commented, I'm unable to find the same CRC they transmit. I added two other examples of transmitted frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With two examples, you can XOR them, which eliminates initial value and final xor, as if both were 00:

```
C0 01 03 02 02 00 CRC is D3
C0 01 05 02 02 00 CRC is DA
---------------------------
00 00 06 00 00 00 CRC is 09
```

This confirms that the CRC polynomial is 0x31 (reversed to 0x8C), input reflected, result reflected.

Using initial value 0xDE didn't work, so I tried reversing the bits to 0x7B which works for the three examples in the question. So initial value == 0x7B, the polynomial will also be bit reversed from 0x31 to 0x8C, but the online calculator uses the non-reversed polynomial, 0x31. If you click on "show reflected lookup table", calculate CRC, then look at row 8 byte 0, you will see the 0x8C.

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't understand how the XOR confirms the polynomial is 0x31. But you apparently got it right, I tried using boost CRC library and `boost::crc_basic<8>( 0x31, 0x7B, 0, true, true )` produces the good CRC for all three examples!

Comment: Also, your online generator works when the right options are set. This is great!

Comment: @jpo38 - as mentioned in my answer, the XOR of the two pattern eliminates initial value and final xor value, as if they were 0. This reduced the number of variables to the polynomial, and if input and result are reflected, and since the document stated the polynomial was 0x31, that matched CRC_MAXIM from the web site.

Comment: OK, again, thanks for your help, I can now compute the CRC with boost and achieve wat I wanted!